# iOS Swift 3 "Login" apps: Best Method for storing/passing a User

Tags: ios

I was simply wondering what the best practice(s) were for passing/storing a User (I created a custom "User" class) when using a login-type application? I am trying to pass the appropriate logged-in user from the login screen to the rest of the application(embedded in a tab bar) or store it appropriately.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's a pretty broad question, but one option would be to have a singleton class to store (and retrieve) those details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a singleton is a tested (and my method-of-choice) practice when it comes to storing something like a user.

This [link](https://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton) here should be a good starting place for you!

This [link](https://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/) is more relevant for swift.